# Issue in InApp Purchase, ItunesConnect

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect, subscription

I have submitted my inApp subscription product without the binary build yesterday. So it is in "waiting for review" state. But I want to remove that subscription from the review. Can anybody help me with the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You simply remove that by following steps:

Spep 1: Go to My Apps and select the app and version that is **waiting for review**.

Step 2: At the top, next to the blue **“i”** info icon, click the link to **“remove this version from review.”**

Step 3: Delete the binary: scroll down to find the build and hover over it; a minus button appears. Click it. Despite what it implies, this doesn’t actually delete the build (or build version number) from iTunes.
Make sure to click Save.

**Upload New Build**

This is the critical step: you can’t use the exact same build/version number, but you can keep the major portion of it. You must update the app’s version number … my previous version was going to be 1.0.3, which I wanted to keep. So, I changed it to 1.0.3.1.

Build the app for production and upload to the store using Xcode as usual.
Back in iTunes Connect, after a brief wait for it to show up, select the new build and again click Save.

Then click Submit for Review and finish the remainder of the submissions steps.

For more information 
http://skypanther.com/2015/06/update-a-waiting-for-review-app-and-keep-the-version-number/

Comment: I have not uploaded any binary build. I have just submitted the inApp Purchase subscription.

Comment: Check this link https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deve4e779617

Comment: are you facing any issue ?